# Tableau - Conditional Color based on number of records

Tags: tableau-api, visualization

I have a Tableau dashboard I created in order to monitor the number of records that flow into each data source per day. This is done to make sure the data health is good and there are no errors while data flows in. I've included a screenshot of the basic idea. Each data source has a trend graph with shapes that change based off the percentage change in data above or below the average each morning. What I'm trying to do is create a color block up top for each section (there is only one green bar right now) that will change to red if that data source is "High Alert" and will stay green if it's "Med Alert" or "OK":

[image: Screenshot of Dashboard so far]

So far, I am assuming I will need to make a new sheet for each section, thus having a green or red bar above each.

I know the logic will follow an "if, then" format. I'm not sure how to get the color coordination to be automatic?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think just using the calculated field in the way you are doing it is right.  Just edit the colors after adding it on marks card

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated field as you were going to do to group the status of Medium and Ok as: IF [status] = "High Alert" THEN "High Alert" ELSE "Med Alert or OK". Alternatively you can use the group function too. Then You can use this in every section as you were thinking.

If you want to coordinate the colours to align in every section, you can edit the colours to ensure their consistent if they are not by default.